# How to include listbox in wpf datagrid control

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

want to include listbox in wpf datagrid control when datgrid click the cell, as like as outlook calander..

see - [this image](http://www.componentone.com/newimages/Products/Screenshots/StudioSilverlight/C1Scheduler/Scheduler_Grouping_sm.png)

My Xaml Code

```
<DataGrid Name="Grid1" Height="550" Width="850" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserAddRows="False" AreRowDetailsFrozen="False" SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader" SelectedCellsChanged="Grid1_SelectedCellsChanged" CellEditEnding="Grid1_CellEditEnding" LoadingRow="Grid1_LoadingRow" SelectionMode="Extended">
            <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">  
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                      AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, 
                                      Path=Item.Time}" FontSize="16"  />
                        <TextBlock Text="00" Foreground="#9493CF"   />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
            <DataGrid.Style>
                <Style TargetType="DataGrid">
                    <Setter Property="AlternatingRowBackground" Value="LightYellow"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Style>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Sunday" Binding="{Binding Sunday}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Monday" Binding="{Binding Monday}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tuesday" Binding="{Binding Tuesday}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Wednesday" Binding="{Binding Wednesday}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Thursday" Binding="{Binding Thursday}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Friday" Binding="{Binding Friday}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Saturday" Binding="{Binding Saturday}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu x:Name="LeftClickMenu">
                    <MenuItem Header="New Appointment" Click="MenuItem_Click"/>                  
                    <Separator/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Exit"/>
                </ContextMenu>
            </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        </DataGrid>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd replace each of your DataGridTextColumns with a DataGridTemplateColumn like this:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Sunday" CellEditingTemplate="{StaticResource ListboxCellTemplate}">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Sunday}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

And then you'll also need to add a resource for your editing mode where you switch to the listbox template:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="TextCellTemplate" >
            <TextBlock Text="Foo!" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ListboxCellTemplate" >
            <ComboBox>
                <ComboBoxItem>Foo</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>Bar</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>Baz</ComboBoxItem>
            </ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
```

Obviously I'm cutting a lot of corners here, but it should give you the general idea. One problem with this code is that the user will need to click twice on a cell to bring up the list box i.e. once to give it focus and again to switch to edit mode, there's [an article on the codeplex site](http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Single-Click%20Editing) showing how to get around that.

Comment: yes sir, you idea was great, one thing is if i put datagrid resources it through 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' error. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f76fdf5d-a9cd-4f42-b2a0-ad560744a39f/provide-value-on-systemwindowsstaticresourceextension-threw-an-exception?forum=wpf thread said that put this resource as window. then its working.

Comment: Interesting, I wonder why it worked fine on my project, different version of .NET perhaps? (I'm on 4.5). Thanks for the feedback, I'll keep an eye out for that one in future.

Comment: :-0 oh may be sir, i am still 4.0 :-)